# Social Distancing Groups at Beaches and similar large venues

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, prevention, infectious-diseases

Government agencies (for this conversation, assume USA) have provided guidance to prevent COVID-19 transmission.  As it is a holiday, many lockdown weary have flocked to the beaches and similar venues.   Assume that compliance with guidance is perfect.

From a infection transmission perspective: Does it make sense to require groups be limited to people that live in the same household?  As I understand it, in practice, said groups are not strictly same household members.

Comment: Lacks prior research. Primarily opinion based. Unclear what you're asking. (What do you understand to be the case, that it's not required or that it doesn't make sense?)

Comment: Yes it makes sense. The less people, the less probability to an infection transmission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDC advice is pretty clear as to staying inside your own group

> Do: Stay 6 feet away from others (“social distancing”) and take other steps to prevent COVID-19
>
> If a park, beach, or recreational facility is open for public use, visiting is okay as long as you practice social distancing and everyday steps such as washing hands often and covering coughs and sneezes. Follow these actions when visiting a park, beach, or recreational facility:
>
> Stay at least six feet from others at all times. This might make some open areas, trails, and paths better to use. Do not go into a crowded area
>
> **Avoid gathering with others outside of your household**
>
> Wash hands often with soap and water for at least 20 seconds, especially after going to the bathroom, before eating, and after blowing your nose, coughing, or sneezing
>
> Bring hand sanitizer with at least 60% alcohol to use if soap and water are not available.

https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/daily-life-coping/visitors.html